# Scalajs tests not running when using Node.js instead of Rhino

Tags: sbt, scala.js

I am currently working on a Scala.js library intended to be exposed as a JS library. To make my tests run faster I added the option as per scalajs's [Basic Tutorial](https://www.scala-js.org/tutorial/basic/)

`scalaJSUseRhino in Global := false`

However when I run the tests in sbt nothing seems to happen:

```
clean
project myprojectJS
test
last
```

Here are the relevant outputs from the `last` command

```
[debug] Loading JSEnv with linked file /home/jacob/proj/mastermind/js/target/scala-2.11/mastermind-test-fastopt.js
[debug] Subclass fingerprints: List()
[debug] Annotation fingerprints: List()
```

Nothing seems to be happening after JSEnv has been loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was since I was writing a library that'll be exposed as a Javascript module, I had the following config in SBT:

```
scalaJSOutputWrapper := ("var __ScalaJSEnv = { exportsNamespace: exports };", ""),
```

Which means the test runner JS file produced will be wrapped too, making the output Javascript file essentially do nothing.

Adding this config in SBT fixes the issue:

```
scalaJSOutputWrapper in Test := ("", ""),
```

Answer (score 0):

ScalaJS tests where not running in my environment, too, as long I was using ScalaTest and UnitTest for a `sbt-crossproject`.

```
[debug] Subclass fingerprints: List()
[debug] Annotation fingerprints: List()
```

both fingerprints where empty lists (running `sbt -v -d` for verbosity + debug informations)

I switched then to `uTest` (because of `sbt-crossproject`), 
added to my `build.sbt` settings:

```
testFrameworks += new TestFramework("utest.runner.Framework"),
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %%% "utest" % "0.6.3" % "test"
```

Now the `test` log shows...

```
...
[debug] Loading JSEnv with linked file qqqqq/.js/target/scala-2.11/qqqq-test-fastopt.js
[debug] Starting process: node
[debug] Subclass fingerprints: List((utest.TestSuite,true,org.scalajs.testcommon.Serializer$FingerprintSerializer$$anon$3@12662894))
[debug] Annotation fingerprints: List()
-------------------------------- Running Tests --------------------------------
[debug] Running TaskDef(TutorialTest, org.scalajs.testcommon.Serializer$FingerprintSerializer$$anon$3@60e5e39e, false, [SuiteSelector])
....
```